# opacity of div children

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a div which has opacity 0.4. How to make his children opacity 1? Because by default it's taking opacity from parent.

Example:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="opacity">
    <h2>TEST</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.container{
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}

.opacity{
  opacity: 0.3;
  background:black;
  height:100%;
  width:40%
}


.opacity h2{
  color:brown;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-top:15px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

JsBin:  **[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kukov/2/edit)**

How to make TEST fully visible?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

But try this:

```
.opacity {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: @Tomasz Bitowt `opacity` is multiplied across children. If an outer element has `opacity: .5;` and it's child has that value set too (`opacity: .5;`), the computed opacity is the half of the half = `opacity: .25;`

Answer (score -1):

I would do this:

HTML:

```
     <div class="container">
       <div class="opacity">
         <div class="opaque">
           <h2>TEST</h2>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}

.opacity{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 height:100%;
 width:40%
}

.opaque{
  color:brown;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-top:15px;
}
```

I avoid setting opacity on an dom element, period, if it is otherwise avoidable for the reason explained in the comment by @feeela. Niet's answer is correct, additionally you do no need opacity on the on h2 element, but for sake of nesting, it might make sense to wrap that in it's own div for flexibility.

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted when my answer is more complete and offers explanation. Poor downvote IMHO whoever you were, without a comment as to why.